# Working on joining several tables to obtain a desired result

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Need to join several tables which shows each customer and total_value of orders placed by it. Report the customer no and name for the customer and the total_value for the customer who placed the **highest** of orders. So far I have:

```
select customer.customer_num, customer.customer_name, price as total_value
from customer, orders, order_line, part 
where customer.customer_num = orders.customer_num
and orders.order_num = order_line.order_num
and order_line.part_num = part.part_num;
```

This narrows it down, but now I need to answer the initial question, report on which customer had the greatest sum of price found in the part table.

I just cannot figure out where to place this syntax?

```
customer.customer_num > sum(part.price)
```

after joining the four tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select customer.customer_num, customer.customer_name, price as total_value
  from customer 
  join order on
 customer.customer_num = orders.customer_num
 join  order_line on
   orders.order_num = order_line.order_num
   join part on
  order_line.part_num = part.part_num  where customer.customer_num >sum(part.price);
```

Comment: Those joins are a lot cleaner, however; here is the actual question. Create a view called Total_Sales, which shows each customer and total_value of orders placed by it. Now report the customer no and name for the customer and the total_value for the customer who placed the highest total-value of orders. Name the total orders value for a customer as total_value. Show the view with all customers, as well as the report with the details of the top customer.    MAYBE I need to utilize the view to get the answer?